# CARBON_CONSOLE log location on the server

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-esb

When I run the wso2 ESB on my local, I can see the CARBON_CONSOLE logs in my terminal (The command window on windows where I started the server) but on an UNIX server, where do I see the CARBON_CONSOLE logs?

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
[kranthib@server  bin]$ ps -ef | grep wso2 
wso2      2061     1  0 Oct20 pts/0    00:00:00 bash /usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/bin/wso2server.sh
wso2     18772  2061  0 Oct24 pts/0    00:23:40 /usr/local/wso2/java/jre/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/logs/heap-dump.hprof -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -classpath :/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/bin/org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap-4.1.0.jar:/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/bin/tcpmon-1.0.jar:/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/bin/tomcat-juli-7.0.34.jar:/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/lib/commons-lang-2.6.0.wso2v1.jar -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/lib/endorsed:/usr/local/wso2/java/jre/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/local/wso2/java/jre/lib/endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/tmp -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/lib/tomcat -Dwso2.server.standalone=true -Dcarbon.registry.root=/ -Djava.command=/usr/local/wso2/java/jre/bin/java -Dcarbon.home=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/conf/log4j.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dcarbon.config.dir.path=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/conf -Dcomponents.repo=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/components/plugins -Dconf.location=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/conf -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.file=/usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/lib/transactions.properties -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.hide_init_file_path=true -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication=simple -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=3000 -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true -DapplyPatches -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
root     23718 23690  0 Oct15 pts/0    00:00:00 su - wso2
wso2     23720 23718  0 Oct15 pts/0    00:00:01 -bash
kranthib 25365 25148  0 13:51 pts/1    00:00:00 grep wso2
```

Thanks 
Kranthi

Comment: @Voicu :  Just a simple question. How were you able to format my log info. Is there any shortcut key that I any use going forward?

Comment: I added four spaces in front of each line to show it as code block.

Comment: @Voicu .. Thanks for the info.. will try to post well formatted questions in future...

Answer (score 0):

You can see the console logs in the terminal that you used to start the server (/bin/wso2server.sh). The logs are also saved in the /repository/logs/wso2carbon.log

Comment: I'm actually to print some logs using the script mediator int he out sequence .. FYI.
             <outSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="Test" expression="get-property('Accept')"/>
         </log>
               <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <script language="js">print(" --Test BKK--");</script>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>

But this doesn't appear in the wso2carbon.log

Also changed for nohup line in wso2server.sh
nohup bash $CARBON_HOME/bin/wso2server.sh > $CARBON_HOME/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log 2>&1 &

Answer (score 0):

Go to /usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/logs folder and do a tail on wso2carbon.log

```
tail -f wso2carbon.log
```

You can see the full log by opening it in a text editor like vim

Comment: I'm actually to print some logs using the script mediator int he out sequence... Please see below..
         <outSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="Test" expression="get-property('Accept')"/>
         </log>
               <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <script language="js">print(" --Test BKK--");</script>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>

But this doesn't appear in the wso2carbon.log

Also changed for nohup line in wso2server.sh
nohup bash $CARBON_HOME/bin/wso2server.sh > $CARBON_HOME/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log 2>&1 &